# How can I show the confusion matrix in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying this code but it doesn't show anything:

ui.R:

```
mainPanel(width = 4,
      tabsetPanel(
        #tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
        tabPanel("Result", selectInput("featureEx", "Feature Exploration",
                                       c("ABC", "AB", "AC", "A"), multiple = TRUE),
                          plotOutput("fePlot"),dataTableOutput("confusionmatrix")),

        tabPanel("Wiki", verbatimTextOutput("Wiki")),
        tabPanel("Plots", tableOutput("plots"))
      )
    ))
```

server.R:

```
#Create Confusion Matrix of Predictions
  ref = matrix(c("P", "N", "P", "P", "P", "P","N"), ncol=1)
  pred = matrix(c("P", "N", "N", "P", "P", "P","P"), ncol=1)
  output$confusionmatrix <- renderPrint({
    confusionMatrix(ref,pred)
  })
```

should I use something else than dataTableOutput or tableOutput to show the results of confusionmatrix?

Comment: Stefano's answer is what I would have posted (though with a bit more code and a screen shot). It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I have used the following command in the ui.R file:

```
mainPanel(
helpText("Prediction Results Using Testing data"),
verbatimTextOutput('output')
)
```

It worked fine

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

you can display confusion matrix in Rshiny using verbatimTextOutput command in UI component and renderPrint in Server component.

Simple example

```
# Have these two line in app.R file
predicted <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0) 
Actual <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0)

# in UI component have below item to display confusion matrix
verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "modelsumr")

# in server component 
output$cnfmatrs <- renderPrint({
  table(predicted,Actual)
}
```